# Facebook SDK doesn't ask user for new permissions

Tags: ios, objective-c, facebook-sdk-4.0

I have issues with the Facebook SDK on a iOS app.

In a previous version of my app, I asked for `public_profile`, `email` and `user_friends`. So my users generate a token with this permissions.

Now I want to add `user_birthday`. So I add this permissions during the login.

Here the problem, the Facebook SDK doesn't ask the user to grant the new permission, it's just prompting "You have already authorized App" when user re-log on the app...

Here the code I'm using to login users :

```
(IBAction)log_in_facebook:(UIButton *)sender {
    FBSDKLoginManager *login = [[FBSDKLoginManager alloc] init];
    [login logOut]; 
    [login logInWithReadPermissions:@[@"public_profile", @"email", @"user_friends", @"user_birthday"] fromViewController:self handler:^(FBSDKLoginManagerLoginResult *result, NSError *error) {
        //Process login
    }];
}
```

Someone can help ?
Thanks.

**EDIT:**

I successfully did this on my Android app, when users re-log, Facebook ask for the new permission and their token contains the `user_birthday` permission.

Comment: Did you get Facebook approval to use that permission in your app?

Comment: try deleting the app/de-authorise from facebook settings and re do again

Comment: Indeed, Facebook approval hasn't been done correctly.